# Problemas de pago con Mercado Pago sandbox.

Tags: android, mercadopago

Tengo una cuenta en sandbox y al utilizar las tarjetas que nos da mercado pago y mas sin embargo utilizamos una tarjeta real.

[image: TARJETAS DE PRUEBA MP]
Nos da un error que dice: `"ALGO SALIO MAL INTÉNTALO MAS TARDE"`, nuestra cuenta es en VENEZUELA.
Utilizamos este [tutorial](https://mercadopago.github.io/px-android/) en la seccion que dice **Collect data to make a payment**

Comment: Agrega más información, revisa en el Logcat si se despliega un mensaje de error, tu código que realizaste, etc.

Comment: El código no genera ningún error, de echo si le cambias el ".addItem(new Item("Item", new BigDecimal("1000"))) " y lo colocas en "1", te arroja que no hay metodos de pagos... Y tambien si le das cancelar, del resto solo arroja ese error que mencione